# My ngStyle is not working with 'OR' Condition In Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am working in Ionic App and I have applied the OR condition in ngStyle but it is not working with 2 conditions but with one it is working fine.

**This is my condition:**

```
 <p 
    [ngStyle]="detailsp?.discount || detailsp?.discountp === '0' ? 
    {'text-decoration':'none'} : {'text-decoration':'line-through'}">
    MRP: ₹{{detailsp.product_price || detailsp.disprice}}
</p>
```

It is not working but with only one condition it is working fine.

**Showing This On Inspect:**

```
  <p 
     ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" 
    style="text-decoration: none;">
    MRP: ₹356
</p>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Seems works as intended. Maybe you have a typo here `detailsp?.discountp`?

Comment: @yurzui. When I applied only this detailsp?.discount, It is working but when I applied both it is not working.

Comment: @yurzui. Is there any syntax error?

Comment: Please test this https://ng-run.com/edit/HF1bJyPFpAvudPzdjiyB

Comment: @yurzui. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think angular working fine but ionic not,
You can give brackets on them to ensure all working fine.

```
<p [ngStyle]="(detailsp?.discount || detailsp?.discountp === '0') ? {'text-decoration':'underline'} : {'text-decoration':'line-through'}">MRP: </p>
```

I think it might work.

Comment: I got the problem, it is taking the last parameter equal to zero. like this :detailsp?.discountp === '0', it is not able to take both parameters value.

Comment: (detailsp?.discount || detailsp?.discountp) === '0', So, I think this will work.

Comment: Any Suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for late reply yes you can always use the solution better to be used ngClass which come with @angular/flex-layout you can use it. ** I didn't check it with Ionic so, you can check it and tell me.

Comment: It's always better to be used classes rather than inline styles, which gives you reusability of the code.